# Slack - Post app template approval across organization with USER ID

Tags: node.js, devops, workflow, slack

I am planning to do a approval workflow from my nodejs application to slack.My basic need is to have a nodejs application where I can able to send a approval message to slack USER ID having their working(professional) email alone in my nodejs applicaiton.

Is it possible to do so , since after some exploration in slack tutorial blog, all I can do is to make a post.message only within my own space with userID.

I can't find any example to send message to slack having only their email ID across organization.Please help me in this regrad.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.